# Help on what animation technique I should use

Tags: animation

I have a very basic character made out of Basic shapes, and I want to animate/pose them. I tried armature but that's[image] more for meshes that look more human-like, and It just does not work here.

What do yall suggest I do?

Comment: You could put one bone per limb, maybe not for the knee and elbow, you could parent them to the upper arm / thigh

Comment: Are you aiming to do 2D or 3D animation? For 2Dsearch COA Tool addon https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187868/2214

Comment: 3D animation with 2d drawing face